# Cookie not set even after configuring

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, mern

I am trying to set cookie in browser by sending name data from register page to backend. It receives the name and console logs it correctly but i cannot see any cookie being set in chrome dev tools even after all the configurations.
Below is my server.js file

```
require("dotenv").config()
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser")

const app = express()

app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200 ,
    credentials:true
  }))
  
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8')
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true)
    res.header(
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
      'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'
    )
    next()
  })  
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false}))
app.use(cookieParser())

app.post('/register',function(req,res){
    res.cookie("name",req.body.name)
    console.log(req.body.name)
})

app.listen(5000, () => {
    console.log("Server running on Port 5000")
})
```

Below is my App.js from frontend

```
import './App.css';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import Register from './pages/Register';
import axios from 'axios'
axios.defaults.withCredentials=true

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/' element={<Register/>}/>
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Below is my Register.jsx

```
import React,{ useState }  from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

const Register = () => {
    const [name,setName]=useState('')
    const handleSave = async()=>{
        const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/register',{name:name},{
          withCredentials: true,
        })
        console.log(response.data)
    }
  return (
    <div>
        <label>Name:</label>
        <input value={name} onChange={(e)=>setName(e.target.value)}></input>
        <button onClick={handleSave}>Send</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Register
```

Below is my Response Headers from chrome network tab

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Date: Sun, 15 Jan 2023 17:16:18 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
Vary: Origin, Access-Control-Request-Headers
X-Powered-By: Express
```

I tried various configurations from various sources but nothing is working. Any help is very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It doesn't look like you are sending a response after setting the response cookie. `res.send()` should do the trick!